# Creating an array from activerecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When in the rails console the following code prints to screen an array of coordinates in geojson format as I expect it to:

```
Bg.
  select("bg_id, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) as my_geo").
  where("ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(-xxx,xxx,-xxx,xxx, 4269), bg.the_geom)").
  map(&:my_geo)
```

The `select` portion however isn't just asking for the json.   What if I would also like the bg_id's in the array too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of inner data structure are you trying to end up with (i.e. where are you going to put the bg_ids)?  E.g. if it's just a hash I think you could change

```
map(&:my_geo)
```

to

```
map{|b| {b.id => b.my_geo} }
```

Comment: Ultimately what I want is a hash with the bg_id's as the keys and the geojson objects as the values.  What you provided here creates an array of hashes.  I used `.reduce Hash.new, :merge` to make a single hash exactly as I would like it.  So I guess my question is answered unless you can think of an better way.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, although this works, I'm not sure I understand why.  This looks like it is calling methods called `id` and `my_geo` on each item of the array... Is that correct?

Comment: Ah, yeah in that case reduce is the way to go. Yes that's correct, it's calling methods. `(&:my_geo)` is shorthand for `{|obj| obj.my_geo}`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the map and active record objects.

```
results = Bg.select("bg_id, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) as my_geo").
where("ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(-xxx,xxx,-xxx,xxx, 4269), bg.the_geom)")
```

And then:

```
results[0].bg_id
results[0].my_geo
```

Or use map if you want an array of something else.
Like an array of arrays [[bg_id1,my_geo1],[bg_id2,my_geo2]...]:

```
results.map{|b| [b.bg_id,b.my_geo] }
```